# Unable to execute TestNG Suite file via command line

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to execute a TestNG Suite file via the command line in order to initiate a regression run.
Currently I am doing this through my Eclipse IDE successfully by right-click on the "testng.xml" file then selecting Run As > TestNG Suite.

However, when I try to run it via the command line, I get an error message. Steps below:

- I navigate to the directory where my "testng.xml" file is saved. e.g. C:\Users\xxx\Documents\eclipse projects\Automated Testing\config
- Run the command:

  `java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

The above command generates the below response:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
```

- I tried setting the classpath to include all of the selenium and testNG Jar files as per below:

  `set classpath C:/Users/xxxx/Downloads/selenium-java-2.25.0/selenium-2.25.0/libs/*`

However, this generates the below error message:

```
Environment variable classpath C:/Users/xxxx/Downloads/selenium-java-2.25.0/selenium- 2.25.0/libs/* not defined
```

I have looked on the testNG Documentation (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) and this just says that testNG has to be in your classpath, so now I am a bit stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Either methods work :)

Method **#1**

```
cd C:\Workspace\projectname
java -cp C:\Workspace\projectname\lib\*;C:\Workspace\projectname\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Method **#2**

```
cd C:\Workspace\projectname
set ProjectPath=C:\Workspace\projectname
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\lib\*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @siemic, I have finally got it working now. Basically you just need
to run the two commands below:

1. set classpath=..\bin;C:\libs\selenium-java-2.25.0.jar;C:\libs\testng-6.0.1-nobsh
   noguice.jar;C:\libs*
2. java org.testng.TestNG

It was the first command that I was having trouble with, so just to elaborate I needed to set the following three items on the classpath:

- The BIN Directory of my project. This is because the java files that I have developed are located here.
- The Selenium.jar file, this is because I am using the selenium framework
- The testng.jar file, needed because this is my unit testing framework

Then finally I used a wildcard to include all other JAR files within my libraries folder. The weird thing
is I needed to fully specificy the name of the selenium and testng jar files, or else the tests don't work. Not too sure why.

Anyway it is working fine now and I am able to execute the tests via the command line.