# How to set TestNG in classpath in Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, testng

In order to run TestNG tests on command line, I'll have to set TestNG in classpath. To do so, I went through -

[Unable to execute TestNG Suite file via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800333/unable-to-execute-testng-suite-file-via-command-line)

[Getting error Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng)

which tells that if `testng.jar` is in `lib` folder of the project, then do set path until `lib` folder(like - `C:\Workspace\projectname\lib\*`) in classpath.

But in my case, I'm using Maven project and hence don't have `lib` folder to put jars. In this case, how can I set TestNG in classpath? And hence run TestNG tests on command line.

Comment: Add TestNG as a dependency in your pom file. Don't start using such cripple things like a lib folder.

Comment: I've already added it but when I hit `java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml` on command line, it results into error - `Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG`

Comment: Can you post your POM?

Comment: [Follow this link related to similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng/60665935#60665935][1])

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven , did you try running your tests with the command

```
 mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=<xml file>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn test -D <suiteXmlFile.xml>
```

Add `'-X'` for debug logs, this command works well.

Really recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as above

Below is pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>WeWalkThru</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>
</project>
```